# Live Wall paper force closes

Tags: android, live-wallpaper

My Live wall app force closes when clicked on the Settings button.

wall_setting.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<ListPreference 
        android:key="time_interval"
        android:title="@string/app_name"
        android:summary="something"
        android:defaultValue="3000" 
        android:entries="@array/updateInterval"
        android:entryValues="@array/updateIntervalValues"
    />

</PreferenceScreen>
```

main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<wallpaper xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:thumbnail="@drawable/ic_launcher"
android:settingsActivity="com.zacharia.lunar.WallService"
android:description="@string/wall_desc" />
```

manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.zacharia.lunar"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="7"
    android:targetSdkVersion="15" />
<uses-feature 
    android:name="android.software.live_wallpaper"
    android:required="true"></uses-feature>

   <application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >

    <service 
       android:name="com.zacharia.lunar.WallService"
       android:enabled="true"
       android:permission="android.permission.BIND_WALLPAPER">
        <intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.service.wallpaper.WallpaperService"></action>
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data 
            android:name="android.service.wallpaper"
            android:resource="@xml/main"></meta-data>
    </service>
    <activity
        android:name="com.zacharia.lunar.SettingActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main" 
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.WallpaperSettings"
        android:exported="true">

    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Errors

> 09-14 20:36:53.491: E/AndroidRuntime(542): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
>   09-14 20:36:53.491: E/AndroidRuntime(542):  at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2031)
>   09-14 20:36:53.491: E/AndroidRuntime(542):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2364)
>   09-14 20:36:53.491: E/AndroidRuntime(542):  at android.view.View.onTouchEvent(View.java:4179)
>   09-14 20:36:53.491: E/AndroidRuntime(542):  at android.widget.TextView.onTouchEvent(TextView.java:6541)
>   09-14 20:36:53.491: E/AndroidRuntime(542):  at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:3709)
>   09-14 20:36:53.491: E/AndroidRuntime(542):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
>   09-14 20:36:53.491: E/AndroidRuntime(542):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
>   09-14 20:36:53.491: E/AndroidRuntime(542):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
>   09-14 20:36:53.491: E/AndroidRuntime(542):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1659)
>   09-14 20:36:53.491: E/AndroidRuntime(542):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1107)
>   09-14 20:36:53.491: E/AndroidRuntime(542):  at com.android.wallpaper.livepicker.LiveWallpaperPreview.dispatchTouchEvent(LiveWallpaperPreview.java:199)
>   09-14 20:36:53.491: E/AndroidRuntime(542):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1643)
>   09-14 20:36:53.491: E/AndroidRuntime(542):  at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1691)
>   09-14 20:36:53.491: E/AndroidRuntime(542):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>   09-14 20:36:53.491: E/AndroidRuntime(542):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
>   09-14 20:36:53.491: E/AndroidRuntime(542):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
>   09-14 20:36:53.491: E/AndroidRuntime(542):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   09-14 20:36:53.491: E/AndroidRuntime(542):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
>   09-14 20:36:53.491: E/AndroidRuntime(542):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
>   09-14 20:36:53.491: E/AndroidRuntime(542):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
>   09-14 20:36:53.491: E/AndroidRuntime(542):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>   09-14 20:36:53.491: E/AndroidRuntime(542): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>   09-14 20:36:53.491: E/AndroidRuntime(542):  at com.android.wallpaper.livepicker.LiveWallpaperPreview.configureLiveWallpaper(LiveWallpaperPreview.java:113)
>   09-14 20:36:53.491: E/AndroidRuntime(542):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   09-14 20:36:53.491: E/AndroidRuntime(542):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
>   09-14 20:36:53.491: E/AndroidRuntime(542):  at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2026)
>   09-14 20:36:53.491: E/AndroidRuntime(542):  ... 20 more
>   09-14 20:36:53.491: E/AndroidRuntime(542): Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.zacharia.lunar/com.zacharia.lunar.WallService}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
>   09-14 20:36:53.491: E/AndroidRuntime(542):  at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1404)
>   09-14 20:36:53.491: E/AndroidRuntime(542):  at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1378)
>   09-14 20:36:53.491: E/AndroidRuntime(542):  at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:2749)
>   09-14 20:36:53.491: E/AndroidRuntime(542):  at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:2855)
>   09-14 20:36:53.491: E/AndroidRuntime(542):  ... 24 more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `main.xml`

```
    android:settingsActivity="com.zacharia.lunar.WallService"
```

should read;

```
    android:settingsActivity="com.zacharia.lunar.SettingActivity"
```